# Error while updating software Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, xorg, xserver

I am getting below error while updating software.

Edit : I am getting the same error when I run '**sudo apt-get upgrade**'.

```
[  1201.873] _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed

[  1201.873] _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
[  1201.874] (EE) 

Fatal server error:
[  1201.874] (EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE) 
[  1201.874] (EE) 

Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[  1201.874] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.

[  1201.874] (EE) 
[  1201.874] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file
```

**Log File Output (`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`)**

```
[   197.261] _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed

[   197.261] _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
[   197.261] (EE) 

Fatal server error:
[   197.261] (EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE) 

[   197.261] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 

[   197.261] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   197.261] (EE) 
[   197.261] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Step 1:  [image]

Step 2 (Error message): [image]

Step 3: [image]

Comment: Please provide your release of Ubuntu, your command, and where you copied that information from.

Comment: @guiverc I have edited the question. I am not using any command, I was just updating the software packages. Please check the screen shot from dropbox link.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when i first installed the 18.04 LTS version for the first time it's the issue with the '**xserver-xorg**' what i done was is reinstalling xserver-xorg

before you reinstall it remove  .XAuthority files by using this command:

```
sudo rm /home/[your username]/.XAuthority*
```

reinstall xserver-xorg by using this command :

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg
```

hope this answer will fix your issue.

Comment: ".XAuthority*" I can't find this file in that path.

Comment: did you change the username  to your username?

Comment: if you done that then. go ahead and do step two

Comment: Yes. I have changed the username, but I can't find this  XAuthority file in that folder. And when I run "sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg" command I get the same exact error.